# How can I get the in and out edges weights for each neuron in a neural network?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

Say I have the following network

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(1, 2)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(2, 3)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(3, 1)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

net = Model()
```

I know that I can access the weights (i.e edges) at each layer:

```
net.fc1.weight
```

However, I'm trying to create a function that randomly selects a neuron from the entire network and outputs it's in-connections (i.e the edges/weights that are attached to it from the previous layer) and its out-connections (i.e the edges/weights that are going out of it to the next layer).

pseudocode:

```
def get_neuron_in_out_edges(list_of_neurons):
    shuffled_list_of_neurons = shuffle(list_of_neurons)

    in_connections_list = []
    out_connections_list = []

    for neuron in shuffled_list_of_neurons:
        in_connections = get_in_connections(neuron) # a list of connections
        out_connections = get_out_connections(neuron) # a list of connections

        in_connections_list.append([neuron,in_connections])
        out_connections_list.append([neuron,out_connections])
    
    return in_connections_list, out_connections_list
```

The idea is that I can then access these values and say if they're smaller than `10`, change them to `10` in the network. This is for a networks class where we're working on plotting different networks so this doesn't have to make much sense from a machine learning perspective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's ignore biases for this discussion.

A linear layer computes the output `y` given weights `w` and inputs `x` as:
`y_i = sum_j w_ij x_j`

So, for neuron `i` all the incoming edges are the weights `w_ij` - that is the `i`-th *row* of the weight matrix `W`.

Similarly, for input neuron `j` it affects all `y_i` according to the `j`-th *column* of the weight matrix `W`.

Comment: Yea the biases are irrelevant as I'm just interested in plotting the edges. I'm a bit confused about the weight matrix `W`. Is this matrix per layer? Because each layer is not the same shape

Comment: Each layer has its own weight matrix `W` of size `num_outputs`x`num_inputs`. It's the matrix `net.fc1.weight` you mentioned in your answer. So, for a neuron, you can find the incoming edges in the corresponding _row_ in the layer leading to that neuron, and the outgoing edges in the corresponding _column_ in the layer succeeding that neuron.